# Proper Kubuntu KDE 5 Wastebin desktop icon config

Tags: kubuntu, icons, kde, trash

After installing Kubuntu 16.04, I choose the folder view layout for my desktop. Everything was working fine until today: The trash bin folder cannot be opened anymore and when I tried to open gives the following error:

```
The desktop entry file /home/ao/Desktop//trash.desktop has no Type=... entry.
```

I have tried to open the .desktop file and every single line was unreadable.

What I did, was to replace the .desktop entry file with the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=user-trash
Type=Link
Exec=pcmanfm trash:///
URL[$e]=trash:/
Categories=FileManager;Utilities;GTK;
Terminal=False
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=x-directory/normal;inode/directory;
Name=Trash
```

I now have a Trash folder in my desktop that can be aligned with the other folders, but if I drop a file on it it doesn't turn red. If I want the red folder i should replace the Icon line of the file with "Icon=user-trash-full", however when the trash is emptied it does not change colour back to blue.

So far I have tried to use the widget, but it cannot be aligned properly in the desktop grid.

My problem is that I would like to have my trash folder as it used to be (a desktop icon the turns red or blue dynamically and it can be aligned with the other folders in my desktop) without using a kde widget. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for future reference, I have found a solution. I modified the .desktop entry as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Wastebin
Icon=user-trash-full
EmptyIcon=user-trash
Type=Link
URL=trash:/
OnlyShowIn=KDE;
```

It now works perfectly the way I wanted.